# app freezes with FMDB query update ios

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, fmdb

my app freezes when i update a value in database. this is the code i am using to check if there is any value change in the server.

```
 DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.observe(.childChanged, with: { (snapshot) in

        let postDict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
        self.db.updateBook(bookName: postDict!["book_name"] as! String, id: postDict!["id"] as! String)
        self.arrayBooks.removeAll()
        self.arrayBooks.append(contentsOf: self.db.fetchAll())
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    })
```

and this is the database class which has the function updateBook

```
  func updateBook (bookName : String , id: String) {
        let sqlString = "UPDATE magazine SET book_name='\(bookName)' WHERE id='\(id)'"
        if self.fmdb.executeUpdate(sqlString, withArgumentsIn: []) {            
        }
    }
```

when the app freezes i press on pause in xcode to see what errors i am getting. 
the errors are:

```
[FMDatabase executeUpdate:error:withArgumentsInArray:orVAList:]

[FMDatabase executeUpdate:withArgumentsInArray:]

updateBook(bookName:id:)

closure #2 in controller.viewDidLoad()
```

Comment: I don't think those are errors; I suspect it's the stack trace up to the point where you clicked on the pause button. The reason the app is "freezing" is that you are doing a "long running process" on the main thread. For whatever reason, your SQL is taking too long to run...number of DB rows, indexes, triggers, whatever...something is taking too long.

Comment: I haven't used FMDB, but based on the signature...I wonder if you are supposed to use escape characters for the variables in your "sqlString" and pass the values in that arguments array. Maybe that's what is causing problems? Like, maybe that array shouldn't be empty.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the problem by changing the update function in the database class

```
 func updateBook (bookName : String , id: String) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {


        let sqlString = "UPDATE magazine SET book_name='\(bookName)' WHERE id='\(id)'"

        if self.fmdb.executeUpdate(sqlString, withArgumentsIn: [bookName,id]) {

            print("sql string  \(sqlString)")
        }
             }

    }
```

so basically the update will be on the main thread `DispatchQueue.main.async`